# Syntax for object creation specification?

Tags: php, token

PHP uses keyword [new](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new) to create an instance of given class. The description in PHP manual seems rather vague, find it unclear what syntax is allowed here. Which tokens/expressions can be passed to `new`.

```
class Foo {}

// using class identifier obviously works
new Foo();  // => Foo{#2574}
// ... including omitting parens for constructor arguments as optional 
new Foo;    // => Foo{#2577}

// passing class name in a string (mentioned in manual) however fails
new "Foo";
new "Foo()";
new "Foo"();
// => PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

// passing class name in a string works only indirectly, through a variable (why?)
$className = "Foo";
new $className;    // Foo {#2580}

// other expressions resulting in *string* value also does not seem to work
function getFoo() {return "Foo";}
new (getFoo());
// => PHP Error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ';'
```

What all possible syntax for `new` is allowed?
Is there some syntax reference for PHP, where this and other core language constructs are described in detail? Like The Python Language Reference?

Comment: _"passing class name in a string (mentioned in manual) however fails"_ - can you please point out the part of the documentation that led you to believe this was possible?

Comment: @El_Vanja It is right in the 2nd paragraph at linked manual entry: *"If a string containing the name of a class is used with new, a new instance of that class will be created."*

Comment: Not sure how up to date https://github.com/php/php-langspec is.

Comment: @NigelRen Great, that's what I have been looking for. https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/10-expressions.md#the-new-operator Going to dive deep in this reference. Last commit from March '20, hope not outdated too much..

Answer (score 0):

The PHP manual says:

> If a string containing the name of a class is used with new, a new instance of that class will be created.

It can indeed be interpreted in a wrong way (i.e. using string constants: `new "Foo"`), but one can quickly realize you would never do that. If you specify a constant string value, you can also write it in the conventional form (`new Foo`), so there would be no advantage there.

However, there's an advantage of being able to use variables holding string values, e.g. `$className = "Foo"; new $className;`, because it makes it possible to dynamically create class names and instantiate them. Nobody should abuse this possibility, but it can come in handy in some situations.

Comment: I'm aware I can write class identifier directly `new Foo`, instead of its string literal `new "Foo"`, however it does not fix ambiguity of description in the manual. It also leaves doubts and uncertainty about completeness of the syntax itself and its current implementation.

Comment: @dunrix it is probably meant in the sense of “string _variable_”, as opposed to a mere text literal.